# getting hardware information with silverlight

Tags: flash, silverlight, air

i would build an app to take the serial number of hard disk of an other hardware serial number (hard disk, cpu MB). Do you know if this is possible with adobe air, silverlight or other similar technology?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't with Silverlight and I'd hope that would be true of other similar technologies.  There are security and privacy issues with being able to do that sort of thing.

Comment: I need something to take a kind of serial number that can identify the system. 
We would a web app that identify the system of user and crypt a file for pc. 
Any ideas?